# How to achieve better power supply regulation for this remote scenario?

Tags: power-supply

I need to power a 0-5VDC output [ratiometric-sensor](https://www.tme.eu/gb/Document/6366ba3cef7c9cebdf13e5093e192285/HSC-analog.pdf) from 75 meters far away.

But because the sensor output signal depends on the stability and/or the accuracy of the power supply voltage(because of being ratiometric), I'm recommended to set up a local, well-regulated supply closer to the sensor. But I will not have access to AC mains on the sensor side, so I cannot set up a local supply.

How about using an isolated DC-DC power supply at the sensor end as shown in Figure 2 below?(Figure 1 shows powering directly from far away):

[image]

Does Figure 2 provide a better regulation and accuracy for the sensor excitation? If not, what could be a adequate way to achieve this? Does anybody have experience with such scenario?

Comment: Figure 2 will work much better for your application, but be careful about the efficiency of the converter, so you don't put excess drain on your battery. But also, where is the reading of your sensor going? All the way back down the 75 meter cable? Is it being sent as an analog voltage or a digital reading?

Comment: Battery?? I was not planning to use a battery. What do you mean? They want analog transmission(long story) so I will use a voltage-current converter and send the signal as 4-20mA back. Using somthing like this module: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/15aa/0900766b815aa3c7.pdf

Comment: Sorry thought I saw battery somewhere but must have mis-read.

Comment: There are many DC-DC converters SMPS and linear; Isolated non-isolated; and which parameter indicates the regulation quality? I also am not sure 9-->5V is adequate or excessive. Thanks

Comment: Another option to consider might be kelvin contacts. We commonly use that for ratiometric sensors on the end of long cables. Don't underestimate the advantages of decent (i.e. low resistance, shielded and/or twisted pair) cables too.

Comment: @JackB I thought the isolated DC DC converter would take care of the noise due to long lines. But I can use STP anyway.  Kelvin contacts between what? What do you mean by that? Can you make a simple drawing  about what you mean maybe an answer. Since you have such experience I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Btw would monitoring the sensor's supply voltage as well could be used to reduce the error?

Comment: This is what's called an XY problem. You have a problem X, and you 've decided to address it with Y. But now you're worried about Y and want help. Problem is, the question of X is the real issue. So. How, exactly, do you propose to use the output of this sensor? Is there a display or processor, and if so, where is it and what are its requirements? Accuracy and stability should be included. As to your immediate requirements, please note that the sensor only requires 3 mA. As an example, 22 ga wire will only drop 25 mV at this load. Is this a problem?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Im limited to send it analog because they some wants it like that(all channels should be analog input requirement) Thats why I wanted to use a module(-20C environment I dont have skills to build robust one thats why I need a module) which converts to current and send as current. I was thinking to calibrate that way... Regarding power supply maybe you mean the noise will be subtracted at the Wheatstone bridge and what matters the voltage drop which is 30mV in this case.

Comment: Wheatstone bridge? What Wheatstone bridge? First you've mentioned it. How far away? What accuracy do you need? How much will you settle for? If you convert to a current, you'll need to draw that much more current, and your voltage drop will be greater. Why not start with a 9-12 volt power supply, and put a 5 volt regulator at the sensor?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the link to sensor is actually in the very first line of the post. How do you think those sensors interfaced with?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Ooops... spoke too soon, ate my boot. Those sensors are ratiometric, and wheatstone bridge has nothing to do with them indeed.

Comment: @Maple Isnt the output the amplified output of the passive Wheatstone bridge?

Comment: I have no idea what those sensors have inside, but even if they do have WB, it does not cancel the supply noise since the output of WB is directly proportional to Vs.

Comment: Oh I thought the CM noise will be subtracted at the bridge since the bridge is differential

Answer (score 1):

I might agree with Maple that it could be better to use a digital connection but if you use analog there are some things you must take into account:

In both cases (figure 1 and figure 2) you don't have a ratiometric output because you don't have access to one therm of the ratio , the power supply voltage at the sensor side. In the figure 2 it's obvious why , in the figure 1 due the unknown line voltage drop.

I also don't see the reason to have an insulated DC-DC converter, what's wrong with a non insulated one in this configuration? In fact an insulated one would need to be a switched mode one that adds a lot of noise right in the proximity of the sensor.For the 3mA needed you can use a linear stabilizer.

From this point of view the solution in the figure 1 is better.

To really have a ratiometric output you will need to have two more wires for signal ground and signal Vcc that don't have the supply currents passing through

I would rather use this setup instead , at 3mA the voltage drop can be at most of tens of mV order, and do not alter the signal since the supply current goes through different wires. Also the noise from the DC-DC converter is far form the sensor side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlwpn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can also put a linear stabilizer at the sensor side if needed

Comment: 1-) This is a great point, here is an article about it:http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/transducer-sensor-excitation-and-measurement-techniques.html. How to make correction?: Lets the signal in your diagram is measured as 2V but the 5V supply is measured 4V(1V supply voltage dropped)..This means if we relate the pressure to 2V it is an error. Should we correct it this way 5*(4/2) = 2.5V. So we should measure the pressure as if it is 2.5V sensor output. Is that correct?

Comment: 2-) For around 70 meters I can use STP cables. Do you think if I send the signal back as current by a module? Or should I first try the voltage way?

Comment: 3-) What do you mean by insulated power supply? Galvanically isolated SMPS or a linear 5V supply? And "linear stabilizer at the sensor" do you mean a voltage regulator?

Comment: @Genzo 1) Yes it's correct. The document explains very good  pluses and minuses for various solutions. 2) the current output is much resisttant to noise but you will loose ratiometric output and you will need to use a precision stabiliser at the sensor side. Also look if errors added by U/I converter are avceptable. An advantage is that you can use a shared ADC for many sensord. 3) Either SPMS or linear (transformer rectifier and regulator) . Yes, voltage regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Ta-da! You've just invented POL supply! Congratulations. :)

I believe this is how chipsets on the motherboards are powered for the past 10 years or so. Providing you can make/buy DC-DC stable enough for your application Figure 2 is good way to go.

Now, the feedback from your sensors makes me worried. I think digital connection will be much more precise and reliable. Ideally with differential protocol. For example, if your sensor chip has I2C interface you can use something like [AN11075](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11075.pdf) to send it over RS-485 more than 1 km away without any loss of precision.

Here is a [ready-made product](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=pca9600-differential-i2c-long-cable-extender-with-buck-convertor-and-rj45-adaptor) you might find interesting. It extends I2C up to 300m and.. wait for it... it **already has DC-DC** on board. Therer are other modules over there, some feeding power into the line, others using it to power themselves.

As you can see, they support true bus architecture, with one Boost module providing power and data link to multiple Buck modules. You can put it in the box with micro-controller, add several (again, ready-made) DAC modules and then write simple program that interrogates sensors and puts their output to DACs in a loop. This is actually one evening project, come to think of it. For the cost of under $300 per 10 sensors.

UPDATE: Here is an illustration of possible system configuration:

[image]

DACs: you can use individual modules, like [MCP4725](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12918), or go crazy with 16 channel [ADAU1966A](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/EVAL-ADAU1966AZ/EVAL-ADAU1966AZ-ND/4866752) monster (cost is not an issue, right? ;) )

MCU: Arduino, Raspberry or whatever you feel more comfortable with

Boost module: The one I [linked before](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=pca9600-differential-i2c-long-cable-extender-with-boost-convertor-and-rj45-adaptor) or any other ready-made I2C-to-differential converter.

Buck module: The [complementary device](https://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=pca9600-differential-i2c-long-cable-extender-with-buck-convertor-and-rj45-adaptor) to above or a combination of DC-DC module + I2C-to-differential converter.

Amplifier: ADC with I2C interface and desired resolution, like [ADS1115](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/1085/1528-1461-ND/5761229). Or better yet, the link that you provided mentions an option for I2C output straight from the sensor. That would simplify things a lot.

Comment: 1-) Thanks a lot. But for some reason they want analog that's why I thought to convert to current. What could be wrong if I convert and send as current? I was thinking to calibrate out the DC offsets.

Comment: 2-) But in case if I can convince them for serial communication, I need a module which can convert I2C or SPI to RS485. Because Im not sure I can make the PCB quickly and a mistake will cost me a lot. The converter should be very robust professional and work down to -20C. Do you think I can find such ready converter module(SPI or I2C to RS485)? Cost is not an issue

Comment: Well, if cost is not an issue you can go with something like $200 3RS7000, sure. (I never used anything like that, so can't really comment on it). But about 4 of those would probably cover pre-manufacturing cost of AN11075 or PCA9615 based converters. With about $5 per actual unit afterwards. But if your customers want analog... well, they are always right, aren't they?

Comment: Another way would be Im thinking to convert(if I can find a module) from IC2/SPI to RS485 and at the receiver end convert back to analog voltage by another module. I have no prob with cost since it is part of a huge project. My problem is finding modules. What do you think about converting to serial and back to analog at the daq side? Then they would have analog inputs with less noise? My worry would be delay more than 50ms.

Comment: I added link to pre-made product working at 1MHz. Should be enough to not worry about delays ;) Converting that back to analog is trivial, if that's what customer really wants.

Comment: This is not RS485 right? Is it CAN?

Comment: One more last thing. Can I send this sensor data to Arduino via SPI and send data from Arduino using this TTL TO RS485 converter https://www.banggood.com/20Pcs-5V-MAX485-TTL-To-RS485-Converter-Module-Board-For-Arduino-p-1152560.html?gmcCountry=DK&currency=DKK&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=zouzou&utm_campaign=pla-dk-elc2-pc&gclid=CjwKCAjwur7YBRA_EiwASXqIHNNSw0QZ6jLRmQGCUjj8T-qgwb6B4GWcRZHB-ziloeRXyIeIr2IqThoC2_cQAvD_BwE&stayold=1&cur_warehouse=CN ?

Comment: They are using CAN transceivers to make differential signal. But the protocol remains I2C.

Comment: I wouldn't use anything found on Banggood in the industrial application. And I don't understand where would you send data from Arduino to, using RS485. I thought we are talking about _reading_ data over digital link and _sending it out_ in analog format. Have you looked at [this](http://sandboxelectronics.com/?p=1145)?

Comment: See Dorian's answer, one must also measure the Supply/Exct voltage to make it ratiometric.

Comment: That statement is upside-down: the output of those sensors is _already_ ratiometric. You need to know supply voltage in order to make it _absolute_. And you know what's funny: the ADS1115 ADC module that I linked to above is 4-channel device. So you can connect both sensor output and supply voltage to it and calculate real voltage on the host! :D This would reduce stability requirements to DC-DC a lot.

Comment: Yes you are right absolute is the aim. Do you agree the way to correct the error in my 1st question in Dorian's answer? Please see that; I dont know how to make correction by using measured Vsupply and Vsig, so I tried to figure out-

Comment: If you connect both Vs supply voltage and Vo sensor output to 2 ADC channels then you can read both on host and get absolute pressure P = K*Vo/Vs, where K is some coefficient to bring the result into desired range.

Comment: There's an equation at page 6 confuses me(calibration plot). https://www.tme.eu/gb/Document/6366ba3cef7c9cebdf13e5093e192285/HSC-analog.pdf

Comment: Don't look at it, look at the diagram above, it's extremely simple - the output of the sensor changes from 10% to 90% of supply voltage when pressure changes from minimum to maximum of sensor's rated pressure. So, if you use say P = 1000*Vo/Vs then full range of pressure would produce numbers from 100 to 900, or 800 points of resolution.

Comment: The one Im interested is from page 5 it says differential +-004ND = ±4 inH2O. 4 H2O is 1000 pascal. and if I measure Vo/Vs ratio as 0.3 does that mean the pressure is 1000*0.3 = 300 Pa? And this can measure max 900 Pa and min 100 Pa pressure?

Comment: If you want to use differential sensor then calculation is a little different. Look at table 5: when P1=P2 the output is at 50% Vs. e.g. if Vs = 4V output is 2V. If P1 - P2 = 1000 Pa then output is 90% Vs or 3.6V. If P1 - P2 = -1000 Pa then output is 10% Vs, or 0.4V. I am sure you can figure out the rest of the math yourself.